# Bloquear recursos do android

Tags: android

Existe alguma forma simples de bloquear recursos do Android? Por exemplo, remover o Google Play, bloquear a instalação e remoção de aplicativos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pergunta que fez é muito genérica, mas aqui fica uma reposta para o que eu acho que percebi:

- De forma simples bloquear essas aplicações não é possível, principalmente se não tiver acesso root. Porque são aplicações com alto nível de prioridade/permissão, e mesmo que sejam mortas, iniciaram logo que o sistema achar necessário.
- Para remover os Play Services android é necessário ter acesso root, para ter permissão de remover app da pasta de aplicações de sistema.
- Se está interessado em não ter qualquer app da google recomendo a instalar uma ROM limpa.